# List Comprehension Best Practice

Tags: python

I'm very very new to python and I'm writing a compiler program for assembly.

An example line of assembly code would be:

```
@2
```

The resulting line of machine code with should be 16 bits long, with the msb being '0' to represent '@', and the remaining 15 bits being a binary representation of the decimal following the '@'. Each instruction has already been broken down and correctly formatted into a list.

Currently I am doing the conversion as follow:

```
rmw = ['0'+f"{int(x[1:]):b}".zfill(15) if x.startswith('@') else x for x in rmw]
```

This works great, but seems a little bit clunky to me, is this best practice? I think I could probably set zfill to 16, but would rather keep the two parts separate then combine them I think. My background is C programming so this is a bit of a departure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems perfectly fine to me. However, there are two simplifications you can make to shorten it:

1. Include the leading `0` in the f-string so the ugly `'0'+` can be excluded.
2. Take advantage of string formatting to pad with zeros directly in the f-string (with `015`) , avoiding the extra `zfill`.

```
rmw = [f"0{int(x[1:]):015b}" if x.startswith('@') else x for x in rmw]
```